# How do I achieve this typing effect?

Tags: batch-file

I want to achieve this typing effect (it isn't enable delay expression / typewriter effect.)

Example of what I want:

[image]

How would I achieve this ?

Comment: How is that NOT the typewriter effect?

Comment: The typewriter effect is super stuttery. This, is extremely smooth like you're typing it.

Comment: Did you checked my last edit in your previous question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```dos
@echo off
Call :TypeWriter "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011157/how-do-i-fix-this-batch-file-typewriter-effect"
pause && goto Next
::*************************************************************
:TypeWriter
echo(
(
echo strText=wscript.arguments(0^)
echo intTextLen = Len(strText^)
echo intPause = 10
echo For x = 1 to intTextLen
echo     strTempText = Mid(strText,x,1^)
echo     WScript.StdOut.Write strTempText
echo     WScript.Sleep intPause
echo Next
)>%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
@cscript.EXE /noLogo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" "%~1"
echo(
exit /b
::**************************************************************
:Next
color 0C
Call :TypeWriter "Deleting Recycled Items..."
Call :TypeWriter "echo del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\*.lnk""
echo del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\*.lnk"
Call :TypeWriter "echo del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\*.pf""
echo del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\*.pf"
Call :TypeWriter "echo rd /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\Rar$EXa0.*.*""
echo rd /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\Rar$EXa0.*.*"
Call :TypeWriter "echo del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\Rar$EXa0.*.*"
echo del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\Rar$EXa0.*.*"
Call :TypeWriter "echo rd /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\Rar$DIa0.*.*""
echo rd /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\Rar$DIa0.*.*"
Call :TypeWriter "echo del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\Rar$D.*.*"Ia0"
echo del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\Rar$D.*.*"Ia0
Call :TypeWriter "echo del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\etilqs_*.*""
echo del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\etilqs_*.*"
echo Recycled Items Deleted!
pause>nul & exit
::************************************************
```

**NB :** You can change the value as you want of `intPause = 10` to go more slower or faster

Answer (score 0):

I had no idea you could do something like this in Batch, but I found some interesting methods. It's limited, but if you want Batch only...

```
@echo off
call :Sentence Do you understand the words that are coming out of my mouth
call :Sentence Man, nobody understands the words coming out of your mouth!
goto :eof

:Sentence
for %%a in (%*) do (
    <nul set /p ".=%%a "
    ping -n 1 -w 500 1.1.1.1>nul
    shift
)
echo.
goto :eof
```